# How to make a dynamic json list/array with database values

Tags: php, arrays, json, dynamic

I am trying to make a json list to be used for a practice app I am busy with.
   It is supposed to look like this

```
 {
    "title": "District 9",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
    "rating": 8,
    "releaseYear": 2009,
    "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
},<---comma is present here
{
    "title": "Transformers: Age of Extinction",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/3.jpg",
    "rating": 6.3,
    "releaseYear": 2014,
    "genre": ["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]
}
```

and this is the code I am currently using

```
<?php
        require '../../scripts/connect.php';

        $y="";
        $book ="";
        if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die ($db->error)){
      if($count = $result->num_rows) {
             while($row = $result->fetch_object()){


        $y .= json_encode(array(
            "title"=> $row->title,
            "image"=>"http://www.mywebsite.com/posts/img/" . $row->id. ".jpg",
            "rating"=> $row->rating,
            "releaseYear"=> $row->date_added,
            "genre"=> [$row->category, $row->subcategory]

    ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


      }
    }
    }
    echo '[' .$y. ']';


    ?>
```

However I get this...whereby the individual arrays are not seperated by comma's

```
[
{ "title": "This is a test",
 "image": "http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/posts\/img\/1.jpg",
 "rating": 8.7,
 "releaseYear": "2015-09-02 02:19:10",
 "genre": [ "genre", "genre" ]
 }<---no comma here is the problem
{ 
"title": "This is another test",
"image": "http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/posts\/img\/1.jpg", 
"rating": 7.7,
"releaseYear": "2015-09-03 02:19:10", 
"genre": [ "genre", "genre" ] 
}
]
```

my question is how would you go about adding a comma to seperate each json object in this instance.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you actually `json_encode()` is single book arrays. Because you simply paste all these pieces of `JSON` behind each other, nothing adds the comma for you.

In stead of adding comma's manually, you should put all the books in an array and `json_encode()` the entire books array.

This makes sure you have correct `JSON` in the entire output.

**Example**

```
$books = []; // I renamed $y to $books, seems clearer.
$book = ""; // This doesn't do anything remove it.
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die ($db->error)){
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $books[] = [
                "title"       => $row->title,
                "image"       =>"http://www.mywebsite.com/posts/img/" . $row->id. ".jpg",
                "rating"      => $row->rating,
                "releaseYear" => $row->date_added,
                "genre"       => [$row->category, $row->subcategory]
            ];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($books, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```